# Is it possible to pass parameters to F# modules?

Tags: parameters, f#, module

I'm new to F# and learning the basics.

I have two modules. A generic one for tree data structures called `Tree`:

```
module Tree

let rec getDescendants getChildren node  = 
    seq { yield node
          for child in getChildren node do 
            yield! getDescendants getChildren child }

let isLeaf getChildren node = Seq.isEmpty (getChildren node)

let getLeaves getChildren node = getDescendants getChildren node  
                               |> Seq.filter (isLeaf getChildren)
```

As you can see, all functions have a `getChildren` argument, which is a function that
enumerates the children of a node of a given type.

The second module handles the more specific case of XML trees:

```
module XmlTree

open System.Xml.Linq

let getXmlChildren (node : XElement) = node.Elements()

let getDescendants = Tree.getDescendants getXmlChildren 
let getLeaves = Tree.getLeaves getXmlChildren 
let isLeaf = Tree.isLeaf getXmlChildren
```

A specific `getXmlChildren` function for XML nodes is defined and passed to
the curried `Tree` functions.

Now there is an awful lot of code duplication.

Is it somehow possible to do the following? (pseudocode)

```
module XmlTree = Tree with getChildren = fun (node : XElement) -> node.Elements()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

F# doesn't support [functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426239/can-ml-functors-be-fully-encoded-in-net-c-f) so you cannot pass parameters to F# modules. In your example, passing a function which generates children of a node to object constructors is enough:

```
type Tree<'T>(childFn: 'T -> 'T seq) =
    let getChildren = childFn

    member x.getDescendants node  = 
        seq { yield node
              for child in getChildren node do 
                yield! x.getDescendants child }

    member x.isLeaf node = node |> getChildren |> Seq.isEmpty
    member x.getLeaves node = node |> x.getDescendants |> Seq.filter x.isLeaf

// Type usage
open System.Xml.Linq
let xmlTree = new Tree<XElement>(fun x -> x.Elements())
```

For more sophisticated cases, [inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233225.aspx) is the way to go. Particularly, you can declare `Tree<'T>` as an abstract class with abstract member `getChildren`, and override that method in `XmlTree` subclass.

Answer (score 6):

You don't do this with modules, but instead with generics, for example

**EDIT**:

```
type tree<'t>(Children:seq<tree<'t>>)=

    member x.isLeaf()  = Seq.isEmpty (Children )

    member x.getLeaves() = 
        getDescendants Children
        |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.isLeaf())
```

I left out getdescendants, but that should be enough.  Also, some of the type annotations aren't required, but are showing what is happening

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific please?
How would the above example look like using generics?
thx

Comment: John, it seems that you've provided a generic **type** that can **represent** a tree of any node type, but the question was asking about a generic **module** that can **operate** on a tree of any node type.