# How to make F# modules configurable (or make similar effect, like object properties)

Tags: f#, functor

Let's say I have these code:

```
namespace global
module NumeracyProblemsInTen=
    module private Random=
        let private a=lazy System.Random()
        let getRandom()=a.Force()
        let next()=getRandom().Next()
        let lessThan exclusiveMax=getRandom().Next exclusiveMax
        let pick seq=
            assert(not<|Seq.isEmpty seq)
            lessThan<|Seq.length seq|>Seq.item<|seq
    module UsedNumbers=
        let min,max=1,9 // *want to make these data variable*
        let numbers={min..max}
        let atLeast a=numbers|>Seq.skipWhile((>)a)
        let atMost a=numbers|>Seq.takeWhile((>=)a)
        module Random=
            let private pick=Random.pick
            let pickNumber()=pick numbers
            let atMost=atMost>>pick
    open UsedNumbers
    module AdditionInTen=
        module Addends=
            let max=max-min
            let numbers={min..max}
            let pick()=Random.pick numbers
        open Addends
        let quiz()=
            let addend=pick()
            addend,Random.atMost<|min+max-addend
        let calc(addend,another)=addend+another
    module MultiplyInTen=
        let quiz()=
            let multipiler=Random.pickNumber()
            multipiler,Random.pick{min..max/multipiler}
        let calc(multipiler,another)=multipiler*another
    module SubtractionInTen=
        let minSubtrahend,minResult=min,min
        let minMinuend=minSubtrahend+minResult
        let minuends=atLeast minMinuend
        let quiz()=
            let minuend=Random.pick minuends
            minuend,Random.pick{minSubtrahend..minuend-minResult}
        let calc(minuend,subtrahend)=minuend-subtrahend
    module DeviditionInTen=
        let devisible devidend deviser=devidend%deviser=0
        let findDevisers devidend=numbers|>Seq.filter(devisible devidend)
        let findDeviditions devidend=findDevisers devidend|>Seq.map(fun deviser->devidend,deviser)
        let problems=Seq.collect findDeviditions numbers
        let quiz()=Random.pick problems
        let calc(devidend,deviser)=devidend/deviser
    type Problem=Addition of int*int|Subtraction of int*int|Multiply of int*int|Devidition of int*int
    let quiz()=
        let quizers=[AdditionInTen.quiz>>Addition;SubtractionInTen.quiz>>Subtraction;
            MultiplyInTen.quiz>>Multiply;DeviditionInTen.quiz>>Devidition]
        quizers|>Random.pick<|()
    let calc problem=
        match problem with
            |Addition(addend,another)->AdditionInTen.calc(addend,another)
            |Subtraction(minuend,subtrahend)->SubtractionInTen.calc(minuend,subtrahend)
            |Multiply(multipiler,another)->MultiplyInTen.calc(multipiler,another)
            |Devidition(devidend,deviser)->DeviditionInTen.calc(devidend,deviser)
module NumeracyProblemsUnderOneHundred=
    module UsedNumbers=
        let min,max=1,99
        // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    // OMG! Do I must copy all the previous code here?
```

If I use oo/types, I can simply define Max as a property, is there a good way to resolve the same scene without object/types but only modules/immutable bindings way? A bit of more complex scene should be also considered, more configurable data, with more usage in different ways.

Comment: Is a [functor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2030863/1243762) what you seek? F# does not have them.

Comment: Not at all clear what you're trying to do here. Consider rephrasing your question.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Ok. Comment added to the code part.

Comment: @GuyCoder Thank you!

Comment: Of interest: [If SML.NET had functors why can't F#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14777522/1243762)

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems to me that your code is designed to generate a random mathematical operation which you can then calculate the result of.  I found this code quite difficult to decipher, it appears that you're trying to use `modules` like object oriented `classes` which contain internal state and that isn't really a good way to think about them.

You can achieve much more granular code reuse by thinking about smaller, composable, units of code.

Here is my attempt at this problem:

```
type Range = {Min : int; Max : int}

type Problem= 
    |Addition of int*int
    |Subtraction of int*int
    |Multiplication of int*int
    |Division of int*int

module NumeracyProblems =
    let private rnd = System.Random()

    let randomInRange range = rnd.Next(range.Min, range.Max+1)

    let isInRange range x = x >= range.Min && x <= range.Max

    let randomOpGen() = 
        match randomInRange {Min = 0; Max = 3} with
        |0 -> Addition
        |1 -> Subtraction 
        |2 -> Multiplication
        |3 -> Division

    let calc = function
        |Addition (v1, v2) -> Some(v1 + v2)
        |Subtraction (v1, v2) -> Some(v1 - v2)
        |Multiplication (v1, v2) -> Some(v1 * v2)
        |Division (v1, v2) -> 
            match v1 % v2 = 0 with 
            |true -> Some(v1 / v2)
            |false -> None

    let quiz range =
        let op = randomOpCtor()
        let optionInRange x =
            match isInRange range x with
            |true -> Some x
            |false -> None
        Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> randomInRange range, randomInRange range)
        |> Seq.map (op)
        |> Seq.find (Option.isSome << Option.bind (optionInRange) << calc)
```

I've created a `Range` record to contain the range data I'm going to be working with.

My `randomInRange` function generates a random number within the specified range.

My  `isInRange` function determines whether a given value is within the supplied range.

My `randomOpGen` function generates a number in the range of 0-3 and then generates a random type constructor for `Problem`: `Addition` when the random value is 1, `Subtraction` when 2, etc.

(You might wonder why I've defined this function with a `unit` argument rather than just accepting the tuple, the answer is so that I can get it to generate operators with equal likelihood later.)

My `calc` function resolves the arithmetic by performing the appropriate operation.  I've modified the result of this function so that it handles integer division by returning `Some result` for cases where the remainder is 0 and `None` otherwise.  All the other computations always return `Some result`.

---

`quiz` is where the magic happens.

First I generate a random operator, this will be the same for every element in the sequence later - hence the importance of the `()` I mentioned earlier.

I generate an infinite sequence of integer tuples from the supplied range and, using `map`, generate an operation (the one I created earlier) on each of these tuples.

I then use `Seq.find` to find the first occurrence of a result that's both within the range that I specified and has a valid result value.

---

Now let's try this code:

> ```
> let x = NumeracyProblems.quiz {Min = 1; Max = 9}
> x
> NumeracyProblems.calc x;;
> val x : Problem = Addition (2,7) 
> val it : int option = Some 9
> ```

Now let's change the range

> ```
> let x = NumeracyProblems.quiz {Min = 1; Max = 99}
> x
> NumeracyProblems.calc x
> val x : Problem = Division (56,2)
> val it : int option = Some 28
> ```

As you can see, this version of the code is completely agnostic to the integer range.

Comment: The life of being on SO, the effort but into an answer is inverse proportional to the return in points.

Comment: @GuyCoder It's probably because I didn't answer immediately.  No one looks at the questions once they've dropped further down the list.

Comment: Well, I'm keep reviewing this question, I have voted this answer cause it is good, but it not the answer correspond to my question indeed. I want to write an expandable code, but this example is everything-known-on-start. @GuyCoder

Comment: And I still want to keep wait for future answerings.